# CSS - "Hover to Scale" disturb position of Other DIVs

Tags: html, css, scale

My question is, why position of Div changes when the link-button scales? And How to avoid this?

```css
.link-button {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #018dc4;
  font: normal normal bold 1em/normal Arial Black;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  text-align: center;
  background: #12d27c;
}

.link-button:hover {
  padding: 17px 27px;
}

div{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<a href"#" class="link-button">Lorem</a>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: You can avoid it but removing it from the context, e.g. you can set your link-button as `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the padding on hover, change the transform property, like so. This property is not going to change the actual height of your element, and thus not moving the div below.

```
.link-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

And if you want to only change the horizontal scale, use

```
transform:scaleX(yourvalue);
```

Comment: Its Working. Thank you so much :)